# Can someone explain this UML diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

[image]

This is embarrassing, I apologize for not including the diagram image ( I thought I included it, but I should be more careful and verify it in the post )

I know almost nothing about UML, but to my knowledge an arrow with hollow head represents inheritance relationship ( ie `ANDSpecification` class inherits from `CompositeSpecification` class ), while the other type of arrow tells us we can navigate from `ANDSpecification` to `CompositeSpecification`?

a) But why does the diagram connecting `ANDSpecification` and `CompositeSpecification` contain both types of arrows? Perhaps because in addition to `ANDSpecification` inheriting from `CompositeSpecification`, it also has a property of type `CompositeSpecification`?

b) What is the meaning of numbers next to arrows?

Answer (score 8):

First of all, could you please provide the source of your class diagram implementation, your inputs are not clear enough to determine the realtionships between the classes.

- (A) There are two types of arrows, the arrow with a rectangular head describes "**Generalization**".

> The specific classifier inherits part of its definition from the
>   general classifier. The general classifier is at the arrow end of the
>   connector. Attributes, associations, and operations are inherited by
>   the specific classifier. Use the Inheritance tool to create a
>   generalization between two classifiers.

- The second type of arrows describes "**Association**"

> A relationship between the members of two classifiers. There are two
>   types of it, Aggregation and Composition.

- (B) The numbers beside arrows simply describes "**Multiplicity**"

> Multiplicity of an association end is the number of possible instances
>   of the class associated with a single instance of the other end.

```
  ┬─────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬
  │  Multiplicities         |      Explanation                                      |
  │                         |                                                       | 
  ├─────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼
  |0..1                     | zero or one instance.                                 | 
  ├─────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼
  |0..*  or  *              | no limit on the number of instances (including none)  | 
  ├─────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼
  |1                        | exactly one instance                                  | 
  ├─────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼
  |1..*                     | at least one instance                                 | 
  ├─────────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼
```

You can find helpful examples in the links below.

[Explanation of the UML arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874049/uml-arrows-pointers-explanation)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409437%28VS.100%29.aspx

http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/UML_class_diagram

Comment: A - Are you certain those numbers specify multiplicity? Values used for multiplicity are *, 0 and 1, while one of the numbers in the diagram is 2?! B - "please provide the source of your class diagram implementation, your inputs are not clear enough to determine the realtionships between the classes." It's taken from DDD:Tackling Complexity in The heart of software.

Comment: @user437291 The numbers aren't restricted to zero one and many! It is saying that an `OR Specification` refers to two other specifications, in either order, presumably as it is satisfied if either of the two is satisfied. Personally I would have designed it as 2..* so you don't have to have extra `or` steps if you have a choice of more than two specifications - having a fixed number which isn't 1 is very often a design smell.