# Why does the class have a dashed line once and a normal line once?

Tags: design-patterns, uml, decorator

I have a task which requires me to draw a UML diagram based on the description. I have received the solution (see the photo). However, I can't figure out the solution and have a few questions why the solution is the way it is. I have described these below.

**Description**:

The contract of a prepaid cell phone should be modelled and implemented. A basic contract has a contract number (of type int) and a balance (of type double), but no monthly charges. The contract number is not automatically generated, but is to be set as a parameter by the constructor as well as the initial balance. The balance has a getter and a setter.
The following options can be added to a contract (if needed also several times):

- 100 MB of data (monthly charge 1.00 €)
- 50 SMS (monthly charge 0.50 €)
- 50 minutes (monthly charge 1.50 €)
- Double Transfer Rate (monthly charge 2.00 €)
  Implement this this requirement with the help of the decorator pattern. All contract elements should be able to understand the methods `getCharges():double`, `getBalance():double` and `setBalance (double)`.

The method `getCharges()` should provide the monthly charge of a contract with all its options selected. The methods `getBalance()` and `setBalance(…)` should be passed through and access the basic contract.

**Exercise**:

- Draw an UML-Diagram with all the classes / interfaces and their relationships,
  fields and methods (no constructors needed).
- Also provide a client class which holds a contract.

**Solution**:

[image: Solution]

**Question**:

- Why does `Option` once have a dashed line and a normal line to `Contract`?
- Why are the `Minutes` not listed as a class like `Data` and `SMS`?
- Why does `Phone` and `DoubleTransfer` have no connection to the other classes?

Comment: All of these connectors are invalid and do not conform to UML specifications.

Comment: @qwerty_so These are the 'official' solutions I have received. That's why I asked the question, because I don't really understand the solution.

Comment: @qwerty_so could you be so kind and show me the 'real' solution of the UML ? :)

Comment: I'm not sure this is a complete solution to your problem, even if the connectors conformed to UML specifications. Have they given you a partial solution that you need to extend?

Comment: This is no place to get your homework done. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874049/explanation-of-the-uml-arrows though the accepted answer use M$ish styles which are not really UML either (look down below for more correct examples). If I were you I'd change the faculty since the provided "answer" is no answer (for other reasons too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Preliminary remarks

There is a serious inconsistency in this diagram:

- Either `Contract` is an **abstract class** (name in italic) and other classes such as `BasicContract` can specialize it (inheritance, with a plain line from `BasicContract` to `Contract`, and a hollow triangle at the `Contract` end.
- Or `Contract` is an **interface** (with keyword `«Interface»` preceding the name of the classifier, or as lollipop), and classes such as BasicContract can realize it (implementation,  with a dashed line but a hollow triangle at the `Contract` end).

There's a serious ambiguity as well:  since at least one hollow triangle was replaced with a tiny plain arrow head,  it is not clear if the other arrow heads are arrow heads (i.e. navigable association) or if they are meant to be hollow triangles (i.e. inheritance).

I'll assume the interface scenario, and I'll assume that the arrow between `Option` and `Contract` is a navigable association;

#### The double line for Option

Option implements the [**decorator design pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).  This means that it implements the `Contract` interface (dashed line + hollow arrow) but it adds responsibilities to an associated `Contract` (plain line, with or without tiny plain arrow head).

Two remarks:

- Very often, you'll find decorators modelled with an aggregation instead of an association. This is not wrong, but is really not necessary.
- Unfortunately, this decorator doesn't seem to add any responsibility. to the original contract.  This is weird, and could only make sens if `Data` and `SMS` would be specializations of `Option` but then again, we have the issue with the inconsistent arrow head (which should then be hollow triangle not tiny plain arrow head), making this "solution" extremely ambiguous, and not at the level one could expect a "solution" to be.

#### Other questions

The missing `Minutes` is an interesting question. Indeed,  one could add a class `Minute`, and use it as a type for properties or operations.  Surprisingly, `Euros` and `MegaBytes` are not modelled either. What do all these types have in common?

The missing links for `Phone` and `Double Transfer` are indeed weird. Perhaps the author ran out of ink, or used a limited demo edition of an UML editor allowing at most 6 connectors?  Probably it is like `SMS` and `Data`, but cross-check the narrative to be sure.

Comment: That dashed line _might_ be a realization, but it is not. Not for sure. It's just "something". (Same for that arrows which are at what likely are associations.) For that simple reason I voted to close this question as opinion based. UML was not invented to drive speculations.

Comment: @qwerty_so I understand.  There were more than one ambiguity, which opens up a lot of option, and requires more explanations to disambiguate. But I felt I could narrow down the ambiguous constructs, and answered with the principle that StackOverflow was not invented to let people helpless and exposed to ambiguous UML without possibility to understanding what's wrong (I just hope that the solution was proposed by another student and not their UML teacher)  ;-)

Comment: Yes. I'm often in doubt when it comes to this kind of questions (and it happens too often, sadly enough). I haven't found an answer to that issue for myself. If I were that altruistic as you it would be easy. But I'm more that kind of grumpy old man...